# How to scale an object relatively to the distance of its edges?

Tags: modeling, scale

In that kind of situation 
[image]
I'd like to scale down the whole object until the top edge and the bottom one are separated of 1 unit distance. How could I do that?

Comment: ..apart from the answers here, just in case you don't already know, you can enter  (Python-like) arithmetic expressions in the value fields in  Blender, which is often very handy.

Comment: Well I never looked that way. Maybe I should. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought I'd add this, to give another option ...

There's a 'Dimensions' panel in the <kbd>N</kbd> Properties region on the right of the 3D view. Since the object is aligned to its bounding box you can:

1. Enter 1 in the 'Y' field of the 'Dimensions' panel. A new scale will appear in the 'Y' field of the Scale panel.
2. Copy-paste the value from the 'Y' scale field to the 'X' scale field.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply the scale of the hexagon.

Comment: Thanks Robin, easier than my solution but having both is no bad thing.

Comment: @barkest This way  only works quickly if the dimension of interest is aligned to the bounding  box .. so your way is more general ..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need.

Enable edge length in the overlay

[image]

Add an edge between the two points. You can do this with fill <kbd>f</kbd> to make sure it does not split the mesh at all.

[image]

Scale the whole object <kbd>s</kbd> and hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> to be more precise. Stop when you get to the correct length and then delete the edge you added.

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly fine for my use. Thanks a lot!